# Can I use virtual desktops with Windows and VNC?

Tags: windows-10, vnc

I manage a Windows computer used for running various servers. There are multiple users who want to connect via VNC, but they often want to use the computer at once, thus blocking each others work. I was wondering if there is a solution? Maybe showing different desktops to users? Using the default Win users could also work, because the VNC server is already set to Win auth.

Comment: idk for VNC, but Windows has a licensing limitation for multiple remote users having simultaneous access - basically the limit is 1 user at a time. The restriction is lifted for Windows Server, but no other version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to buy Windows Server and also invest in enough
CALs (licenses) to accommodate all your friends, and also have
enough bandwidth if your friends wish to view video and other
demanding tasks.

Windows Server only comes with two remote administrative licenses.

In other words, Microsoft in client Windows versions enforces the rule
of only one active user at a time.

Such a multi-user setup requires a careful analysis of the requirements,
to see if the existing hardware can support this usage.
This means memory, disk and more.